# Hibernate subclass to override a column

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

We have an Entity library untouched by our web stack, but our web stack would like to extend existing columns on existing entities with validation constraints.  Here's one example of the "goal":

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Person")
public class WebPerson extends Person {
    @Override
    @Validate("require")
    public String getName() { return super.getName(); }
}
```

Is this possible?  We can't use InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE because that mandates a silly DTYPE.  Person as MappedSuperclass gives us a "Duplicate property mapping of" error. Help! Thanks.

Comment: We're trying not too; adding a nonsense column is no fun, & our DB doesn't support views. But I may give it a try and see if the SINGLE_TABLE attempt works, as ugly as it would be.

Comment: How would you imagine Hibernate would create a WebPerson over a Person without a discriminator field?

Comment: loosely. query what is necessary for whatever is being asked for. if i try and load a WebPerson, ask for the fields necessary. if i try and load a Person, ask what fields are necessary for a person. given that the columns are the same (adding @Column might make this example "more sensical"), Hibernate will never have a problem loading the data: it's the same for all.